# How to get a vector which identify to which intervals the elements belong in R

Tags: r, intervals

I need to sort my vector values into custom intervals and subsequently **identify which element belong to which interval**.

For example if a vector is:

```
x <- c(1,4,12,13,18,24)
```

and the intervals are:

```
interval.vector <- c(1,7,13,19,25)

1st interval:    1 - 7
2nd interval:    7 - 13
3rd interval:   13 - 19
4th interval:   19 - 25
```

...how do I combine `x` and `interval.vector` to get this:

```
element:   1   4   12   13   18   24
interval:  1   1    2    2    3    4
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use `cut`.

```
x <- c(1,4,12,13,18,24)
interval.vector <- c(1,7,13,19,25)
x.cut <- cut(x, breaks = interval.vector, include.lowest = TRUE)

data.frame(x, x.cut, group = as.numeric(x.cut))

   x   x.cut group
1  1   [1,7]     1
2  4   [1,7]     1
3 12  (7,13]     2
4 13  (7,13]     2
5 18 (13,19]     3
6 24 (19,25]     4
```

---

Another option is the very efficient `findInterval` function, but I'm not sure how robust this solution on different variations of `x`

```
findInterval(x, interval.vector + 1L, all.inside = TRUE)
## [1] 1 1 2 2 3 4
```

Comment: The package taRifx has a function between() that might also suit your needs.  It will "classify values into groups based on which numbers they're between."